# Performance and other issues for Python Tkinter drag and drop feature of a huge custom chart

Tags: python, performance, tkinter, drag-and-drop

The final goal is to build a chart, which is y-axis plus main field.
Main field consists of separate boxes (let's say 20x20 pxls). At least up to 500x500 boxes and I hope even more.
The main field is supposed to be draggable.

With Stackoverflow help I chose putting images on a main field canvas, instead of just labels. And using canvas.move() instead of redrawing the elements when dragging.
The y-axis is a canvas as well, but with labels.

This solution is ok for small canvases (100x100 elements), but I encounter delays (lags, inertia) when dragging 500x500-element canvas.

Then I tried to add extra canvas, which is internal. The idea was to move internal canvas (with images) on a canvas instead of just moving images on a single canvas.

Thus, internal canvas has to be placed within a window. I tagged the window with 'canv' tag. And refer to it when calling move function.

But I can capture the window just clicking on a small 1-pxl area around internal canvas perimeter.

What should be changed in order to drag the main field of the chart when clicking on the main field itself, not just 1-pxl canvas outline? Or changed in solution architecture?

And need to keep in mind that y-axis has to be in sync with the vertical movement of the main field. I managed to achieve this sync by previous solutions, but not by the current one.

```
import tkinter as tk
from functools import partial


class DraggableCanvas(tk.Canvas):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)
        self.start_pos = 0, 0
        self.bind('<Button>', self.on_drag_start)
        self.image = tk.PhotoImage(file='images\\image_ .png')  # icon-like 20*20 pxls image
        self.tag_bind('canv', '<B1-Motion>', partial(self.on_drag_motion, 'canv'))
        self.add_images()
        self.add_internal_canvas()

    def on_drag_start(self, event):
        self.start_pos = event.x, event.y

    def add_internal_canvas(self):

        int_canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=200, height=200)
        self.create_window(50, 25, anchor='nw', window=int_canvas, tags='canv')

        for i in range(100):
            for j in range(100):
                int_canvas.create_image(10+j*21, 10+i*21, image=self.image)

    def add_images(self):
        pass
        # for i in range(100):
        #     for j in range(100):
        #         self.create_image(10+j*21, 10+i*21, image=self.image, tags='img')

    def on_drag_motion(self, imgs_tag, event):
        self.tag_raise(imgs_tag)
        self.move(imgs_tag, event.x - self.start_pos[0], event.y - self.start_pos[1])
        self.on_drag_start(event)


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, bg='#303040', width=100, height=480)
    canvas1.pack(side='left', anchor='n')

    for i in range(10):
        lbl = tk.Label(canvas1, text='y_axis', width=5, bg='#303030', fg='white')
        lbl.pack(anchor='n')

    DraggableCanvas(root, bg='grey', width=750, height=480).pack(anchor='nw')
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Tkinter itself is slow

Comment: @Yarik0urWorld , if there is an alternative easy to start with?

Answer (score 1):

I got this:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from functools import partial


class DraggableCanvas(tk.Canvas):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)
        self.start_pos = 0, 0
        #self.bind('<Button>', self.on_drag_start)
        #self.tag_bind('canv', '<B1-Motion>', partial(self.on_drag_motion, 'canv'))
        self.image = tk.PhotoImage(file=r"imgs/pawn.black.png")  # icon-like 20*20 pxls image
        self.add_images()
        self.add_internal_canvas()

    def on_drag_start(self, event):
        self.tag_raise("canv")
        eventx = event.x_root-self.bbox("canv")[0] + self.winfo_rootx()
        eventy = event.y_root-self.bbox("canv")[1] + self.winfo_rooty()
        self.start_pos = eventx, eventy

    def add_internal_canvas(self):

        int_canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=200, height=200, bd=0)
        self.create_window(50, 25, anchor='nw', window=int_canvas, tags="canv")
        int_canvas.bind('<Button>', self.on_drag_start)
        int_canvas.bind('<B1-Motion>', self.on_drag_motion)

        for i in range(100):
            for j in range(100):
                int_canvas.create_image(10+j*21, 10+i*21, image=self.image)

    def add_images(self):
        pass
        for i in range(100):
            for j in range(100):
                self.create_image(10+j*21, 10+i*21, image=self.image)

    def on_drag_motion(self, event):
        dx = event.x_root + self.winfo_rootx()-self.start_pos[0]
        dy = event.y_root + self.winfo_rooty()-self.start_pos[1]
        # The max(..., 0) claps it down so that it can't go off of the screen to the left/top (you can remove it)
        self.moveto("canv", max(dx, 0), max(dy, 0))


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, bg='#303040', width=100, height=480)
    canvas1.pack(side='left', anchor='n')

    for i in range(10):
        lbl = tk.Label(canvas1, text='y_axis', width=5, bg='#303030', fg='white')
        lbl.pack(anchor='n')

    DraggableCanvas(root, bg='grey', width=750, height=480).pack(anchor='nw')
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I think that the problem with your code is that `int_canvas` swallows up all of mouse events that happen inside of it so `on_drag_start` and `on_drag_motion` don't get called. To fix that I bound to `int_canvas` and changed the calculations a bit in `on_drag_start` and `on_drag_motion`. I don't think my code is very efficient so if anyone wants to update it, feel free to do so.

Right now it has a problem where you can drag the canvas outside of the screen. I added a small fix for that by using `max(..., 0)` but that only works for the left/top sides.

As for the lagging problem, I don't see it on my computer but if you still see it, try minimising the number of stuff that `tkinter` has to deal with. For example you can combine some of the images using `PIL` and display it as 1 single image.

Comment: yeah, capture area is good now, thank you!

Comment: 500x500 images works good on your computer?

Comment: no problem with getting out of the screen, I'm assuming I can handle it. At least I have some ideas.

Comment: "As for the lagging problem... ...combine some of the images using PIL and display it as 1 single image." - I implemented this. Concatenating all the small images into a single big image (up to 10,000x10,000 pxls and decompression warning from Python). You were right! No lags as of now. Dragging works smoothly now, but  I need to come up with a solution for interactive chart feature, as it was supposed to be. In the case of a single big image I have to redraw the entire big image.

Comment: and BTW, the performance was the same (with lags) for both single canvas with images and 2 nested canvases

Comment: @mgrechka btw make sure you do as little work as possible in `tkinter` bindings. While the code inside `on_drag_start` and `on_drag_motion` is running, `tkinter` can't update itself. So if you have some expensive computation, do it in another thread and store it in a cache somewhere.

Comment: no computations after I've formed the chart, at least so far. But ok, thank you!